# How to get disk usage stats of a share folder in windows in Java?

Tags: java, windows, filesystems, diskspace, oshi

My shared folder looks like //shared/content and I want to know details like total space and available space of the folder. How can I do that in Java?

I have tried OSHI library but the file stores and disks that it provides does not have this shared folder. For linux it returns NFS file stores but I am not able to figure out how to locate the shared folder and get its space statistics.

Comment: Probably need to use Powershell so add it to tags

Comment: Have you checked the Filesystem / FileStore information, or do you need usage of just that folder within the larger filesystem?

Comment: @DuncG The FS does not have information about the file store that the share folder belongs to. If I get to know the FS where the share folder belongs, I can just get the stats of the filestore. I don't specifically need the stats of that folder but the FS that the folder belongs to.

Comment: Its not clear why you can't use `new File("//shared/content").getFreeSpace() / getTotalSpace` or `Path` to get this information, perhaps edit your question with more details if my answer isn't helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve information on the filesystem via the `FileStore`. This should work for your Windows shares using the UNC path, or the drive letter if you have mapped the UNC path:

```
static void diskInfo(Path p) throws IOException {
    FileStore fs = Files.getFileStore(p);
    System.out.format("%s %d free of %d%n", p.toAbsolutePath(), fs.getUsableSpace(), fs.getTotalSpace());
}
```

Some examples on Windows, :

```
diskInfo(Path.of("C:/"));
diskInfo(Path.of("C:\\"));                // Same as previous line

diskInfo(Path.of("//shared/content"));
diskInfo(Path.of("\\\\shared\\content")); // Same as previous line
```

Some examples on GNU/Linux:

```
diskInfo(Path.of("/"));
diskInfo(Path.of("/some/mount/point"));
```

You can query same information via `File`:

```
static void diskInfo(File f) {
    System.out.format("%s %d free of %d%n", f.getAbsolutePath(), f.getUsableSpace(), f.getTotalSpace());
}
```

Comment: thanks this is what I was looking for, I did not know we can do this.